# how to use an html entity as text

Tags: html, html-entities, entities

I am making a developer page for my website, and I have HTML code for a button to put into their own website. But the code for them to copy has an entity in it, and I need the entity to appear as text. Can anyone help?

HTML:

```
&lt;button id="b"&gt;0&lt;/button&gt;&lt;div id='votes'&gt;&Leftarrow;&lt;/div&gt;
```

P.S. The HTML entity is `&Leftarrow`

Comment: You probably just need to double-escape the HTML entity (i.e. `&amp;lt;`).

Comment: That's an HTML entity??  Since when?

Comment: @andi I think since HTML

Comment: Could you show us the exact code?

Comment: maybe you mean &leftarrow; ?  either way, what is the HTML code you have now, and what do you want it to appear as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the text

<button id="b">0</button><div id='votes'>&Leftarrow;</div>

to appear on the page, as it seems, write it as

```
&lt;button id="b"&gt;0&lt;/button&gt;&lt;div id='votes'&gt;&amp;Leftarrow;&lt;/div&gt;
```

That is, the code in the question but the ampersand `&` before `Leftarrow` escaped as `&amp;`, by normal HTML rules.

However, the character reference `&Leftarrow;` is an addition in HTML5 and not supported by older browsers. It is a pointless risk to use it, instead of the HTML 4 entity reference `&lArr;`, which is considerably more widely supported. Or you could enter the character “⇐” itself, provided that developers know how to use UTF-8 property, as they should.

The entity `&Arrowleft` mentioned in the question does not belong to any HTML version. The names of entity/character references for arrows are very confusing (who would have guessed that `&LeftArrow;` and `&leftarrow;` are the same thing, but different from`&Leftarrow;`?), which is yet another reason to use the character themselves, or numeric references like `&#x21d0;`.

Note that independently of these notational issues, the character “⇐” is has limited [font support](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/21d0/fontsupport.htm). If you only use it in an icon-like manner, using an image, with an adequate `alt` text, is probably a safer option.

Answer (score 0):

Use this chart http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref as guidance, and replace the HTML entities with their corresponding entity reference. So if you have `<` use `&lt;` instead, for example.

Comment: I don't understand what I'm supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use this markup:

```
<button id="b">0</button><div id='votes'>&leftarrow;</div>
```

If you're posting this into some kind of CMS and it's changing your code, try wrapping everything in `<pre></pre>`.